# Excel SUMPRODUCT function using WEEKNUM

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Hi I've got some rather large sheets detailing call status, revenue, etc that I can download directly from my software vendor. Relevant is this column

```
COMPLETED
1/1/2017 00:00
1/1/2017 02:30
etc
```

I am trying to get a count of this by weeknumber for graphical purposes so I created a seperate spreadsheet where I can filter multiple years of data and display in a graph.

I created a table such as:

```
WeekNumber | Count | Revenue
```

I'm attempting to use this formula for the Count but it uses the header cell which gives me #VALUE. If I could skip the header cell I believe it would work but every variation I try fails.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--('2017Q1'!J:J>0)*(WEEKNUM('2017Q1'!J:J+0)=A3))
```

Comment: Have you considered using a pivot table instead of a formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WEEKNUM can not be used in an array.  But you can achieve this with a custom function and here is the code:

```
Function WeekNum2(dates As Variant) As Variant()

    Dim weeks() As Variant
    ReDim weeks(dates.Cells.Count - 1, 0)
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 0 To dates.Cells.Count - 1
        weeks(i, 0) = Application.WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(dates.Cells(i + 1).Value)
    Next i

    WeekNum2 = weeks

End Function
```

Then in your formula, use `WeekNum2` instead of `WEEKNUM`.

Also, please skip the header because that will mess up the formula since it only accepts numbers.  Plus, it is not recommended to use the whole column as `SUMPRODUCT` will slow you down.  Maybe use a range instead to make your life easier.